# In Resident Evil movie, was the T-Virus intentionally released?

Tags: plot-explanation, resident-evil, resident-evil-apocalypse, resident-evil-the-final-chapter

Can you please solve this confusion?

- In **"RE: Apocalypse"**, the spread of the virus was unintended and Umbrella wanted to cover this crisis so the U.S  government sanitized the whole city with a nuclear bomb and made a media cover.

*On the other hand:*

- In **"RE: Final Chapter"** the *T-Virus* was spread by the plan of Dr. Alexander Isaacs the second owner of Umbrella and his board of directors to end the world for a dirty purposes.

Do you have any explanation for that?

Comment: @Paulie_D **BOD** refers to the **B**oard **o**f **d**irectors of Umbrella corporation

Comment: **Evil Plan to Destroy The World (tm) Step 1:** intentionally release killer zombie supervirus. (*check*)  **Step 2:** Publicly deny that the virus was released intentionally. (*check*)  **Bonus:** Convince US government to nuke a city. (*score!*)  **Step 3:** ???  **Step 4:** Profit!

Comment: A good viewpoint @Steve-O

Comment: @Steve-O Then why did they seal Raccoon in the 2nd movie and tried to contain the virus within the city walls? Why annihilate the city if you want the virus/ to spread and the city infrastructure to stay intact?

Comment: @Alex Sealing the city falls under public deniability (step 2.)  Nuking the city is the bonus, as mentioned (it's not every day you get to coerce a world superpower into dropping a nuke at your behest.)  If the bomb *does* succeed in wiping out the outbreak, it's easy enough to release a new batch (or batches) somewhere nearby and blame it on a leak from the city.  And who said anything about keeping the city infrastructure intact?

Answer (score 3):

**There is no mention in the second film that the release of the virus was accidental.** The incident in the Hive when Spence broke the vial with the T-virus was *intentional*; he had [multiple reasons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17020/in-the-2002-resident-evil-film-who-is-the-thief-working-for) to contaminate the facility. Remember that Spence was also a secret operative for the Corporation, and it is likely (although never mentioned) that he was instructed by its authorities to preemptively release the virus, once he discovered that Alice and Lisa planned to infiltrate the Hive and expose its research to the media. It appears that the actions of Umbrella in re-opening the Hive, not taking any security measures, and eliminating civilians are signs of their grander scheme to bring about the armageddon. Aside from these two speculations, the *Final Chapter* makes it very clear that "he [Dr. Isaacs] released it [the T-virus] deliberately". It's revealed in the scene, when Alice and the team enter the Hive and speak to the Red Queen. Therefore, there should be doubt that the Corp. started the outbreak purposely.

Answer (score 1):

The T-Virus was intentionally released, though you are told in the original movie that it was done to cover the tracks of the guy stealing the T-Virus. The final chapter it's explained that this was done to infect the world. They were planning to release the virus anyway, but someone sabotaging things made that part of the plan come faster, and helped keep blame off of themselves. Ultimately-the end result was the same.

Comment: I believed that they hired Spence to do it under the guise of a nation wanting to buy it. He was just a cog in the machine. He didn't really know the greater implications of what he was doing. If this was something entirely out of Umbrellas plan, I don't think they'd have time to cryogenically freeze all the top brass.